# Where do I find the header file for GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT?

Tags: c, opengl-es

I'm getting a `‘GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT’ undeclared` and I'm unable to find the header file, where should it be? I'm using c and OpenGL ES, not OpenGL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Khronos header files are here:

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_es.php

For OpenGL ES 1.x you want this one:

```
#include <GLES/glext.h>
```

... but note that the define is `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES`, not `*_EXT`, as by this point the extension was an official extension for OpenGL ES rather than a multi-vendor extension for OpenGL.

For OpenGL ES 2.x onwards the functionality is core, so you can use use `GL_FRAMEBUFFER` from the main header.

Comment: Thanks! I wish google had given me a result like [this one](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/mesa-commit/2012-July/037933.html). I was totally unable to search for something wich no longer exists.

Comment: In general if you can't find something it's always worth checking other postfixes (`_KHR`, `_EXT`, `_OES`, or no post-fix), as they tend to change over time.